# Syntax Error: "]," invalid syntax - Dash Graph Building

Tags: python, syntax-error, plotly-dash

I am new to Dash and I have to build a web application where I print some data read from a microphone and an accelerometer.

Now I am trying to understand how to setup various graph and information. I am following the example given in the Dash User guide.

The error is at line 23 that is the line where I set data and layout. It seems he doesn't like the ], but honestly I don't know how I can fix it.

```py
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc 
import dash_html_components as html 

external_stylesheets = ['https://codepen.io/chriddyp/pen/bWLwgP.css']



app = dash.Dash(__name__,external_stylesheets=external_stylesheets)

app.layout = html.Div(children=[
    html.H1(children='Hello Dash'), 

    html.Div(children='''Dash: A web application framework for Python.'''), 

    dcc.Graph(id='example-graph',
        figure={
            'data': [
                {'x': [1, 2, 3], 'y': [4, 1, 2], 'type': 'bar', 'name':
                {'x': [1, 2, 3], 'y': [2, 4, 5], 'type': 'bar', 'name':
            ],
            'layout': {
                'title': 'Dash Data Visualization'
            }
        }
    )
])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

- Syntax Error:
  File "app.py", line 23
  ],
  ^
  SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Why is it giving this kind of error?

P.s.: User guide (first example) -> https://dash.plot.ly/getting-started

Comment: your `'data'` element are missing closing curly braces`'}'` have you copied and pasted incorrectly here? there is no value for `'name'` for both your rows unlike in the linked example

Comment: U mean to do like this:
data:[
{'x': [1, 2, 3], 'y': [4, 1, 2], 'type': 'bar', 'name':}
{'x': [1, 2, 3], 'y': [2, 4, 5], 'type': 'bar', 'name':}], ?? Because now it doesen't like the { at the beginning and yes i copied the code correctly

Comment: Also, what is the value for 'name'  in both lines?

Comment: Not dash-specific, this problem is just a regular Python syntax error; you'd get the same error just taking the `{` from `figure={` up to the closing `}` and evaluating it in any Python repl.

Comment: That's still invalid, you've added a key `'name'` with no value, look carefully at the example in the link

Comment: Thanks to all. I've fix it.
I am sorry for the stupid question but i come from C world and all that stuff are useless.. Thanks !!! :)

Comment: No problem @Giulio, Happy to help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc 
import dash_html_components as html 

external_stylesheets = ['https://codepen.io/chriddyp/pen/bWLwgP.css']



app = dash.Dash(__name__,external_stylesheets=external_stylesheets)

app.layout = html.Div(children=[
    html.H1(children='Hello Dash'), 

    html.Div(children='''Dash: A web application framework for Python.'''), 

    dcc.Graph(id='example-graph',
        figure={
            'data': [
                {'x': [1, 2, 3], 'y': [4, 1, 2], 'type': 'bar', 'name':'a'},
                {'x': [1, 2, 3], 'y': [2, 4, 5], 'type': 'bar', 'name':'b'}
            ],
            'layout': {
                'title': 'Dash Data Visualization'
            }
        }
    )
])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

**Output**

```
Running on http://127.0.0.1:8050/
Debugger PIN: 201-392-957
 * Serving Flask app "main" (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: on
Running on http://127.0.0.1:8050/
Debugger PIN: 906-971-228
```